# Architectural Pattern for Angular + Asp.net core Web Api Entity Framework

Tags: angular, entity-framework, design-patterns, architecture, asp.net-core-webapi

I am struggling with how to couple Angular front-ends with Web API back-ends in a way that will allow for abstraction of the domain model /entity framework model for the view and provide a structural standard for developers to follow.

Right now, we publish controllers for entity framework classes.  Database first because the database is pre-existing.  When forms are posted to the controllers, I have created simple c# classes (view model like) that allow for deserialization of the form/request data to a class object that typically differs slightly from the domain/entity model for example the form may post null for a non-nullable type, or a zero-length string instead of null, etc.  This has resulted in a lot code needed to map the “view model” to the domain model.  The code in these mappings has resulted in quality issues mostly due to type exceptions.  I have even standardized creating typescript interface models directly from the domain models to help enforce some standards in the angular code when validating forms, etc.

Has anyone seen a good example of how others are handling this in the world of model-view-whatever?  Coming off of MVC, this seems like a bit of chaos.  What am I doing wrong?  Is there a known pattern that I’m missing in the Web API /Entity Framework?   Else maybe I need to do better at form development to ensure data types are as predictable and compatible with domain models as possible.  Any guidance is appreciated.

Thanks,
Ali

Answer (score 0):

Check aspnetboilerplate architecture, it is very well coupled Angular front-ends with Web API back-ends

https://aspnetboilerplate.com/

[image]